# Mixing window.onload and jQuery $(function(){})

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it OK to mix window.onload and $(function(){}); of jQuery in the same script?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        this.onload = function () {
            // do something
        }

        $(function () {
            //do something
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Why is that necessary ?

Comment: They are two very different things, they can definitely be mixed. Should you mix them? that's an opinion and will depend on the situation. I tend to avoid needing either.

Comment: I was trying some code out there on internet that utilizes window.onload and then there is some other snippet which utilizes the jQuery $ approach. So I was wondering If I keep on doing something like that, then it could cause any stability issue or not.

Comment: @user2860136: Most code on the internet that uses `window.onload` is just using it because a superior dom-ready handler (like jQuery) is not available and coding it properly would shift the main point of the script (or the author just didn't knew it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is perfectly acceptable to do what you asked:

```
// check when DOM is ready
$(function(){
    // place code here 
    console.log('DOM ready');
});

// check when all images, links and assets have been loaded
window.load = function(){
      // place code here 
      console.log('window loaded');
};
```

also you can do this to make sure the DOM is ready before checking the load event

```
// check when DOM is ready
$(function(){       
      // check when all images, links and assets have been loaded
      $(window).on('load',function(){
           // place code here 
           console.log('window loaded');
      });
      console.log('DOM ready');
});
```

or with native javascript for window.load event

```
// check when DOM is ready
$(function(){
      // check when all images, links and assets have been loaded
      window.load = function(){
          // place code here 
          console.log('window loaded');
      };
      console.log('DOM ready');
});
```

Even the JQuery API docs ready() say its ok: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

You can do this to make sure the DOM is ready before checking the window.load event. It can be placed outside yes, but sometimes due to different browser inconsistencies, and other scripts loading in.

Its perfectly acceptable for the window.load event to go inside the ready function to guarantee the window.load event fires after the DOM is ready, and not before.

Since the jQuery ready function, in some instances, will sometimes fire before all images have been loaded. when inside the ready() event, the window.load event will fire immediately once the ready handler is run if all images, links, etc have loaded.

Comment: The JQuery API docs mentions the following:
The .ready() method is generally incompatible with the <body onload=""> attribute. If load must be used, either do not use .ready() or use jQuery's .load() method to attach load event handlers to the window or to more specific items, like images
... Is the body onload same as window onload?

Comment: the jQuery load() event is depricated since jQuery version 1.8 and no longer be used, sibce it will be removed soon from jQuery core. http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ - so that is why I use the jQuery on() method above to bind the load hander on the load event.. the body onload is a inline event that gets attached to the body tag.. the window event us actually the top level in the DOM and the window.load is attaching a load event through the window object.. in my example above you wouldnt need to use body onload attribute.. its best to have your javascript external than inline on attributes

Answer (score 0):

This will work because `$(function () { // ... })` is the short form of `$(document).ready()` and this event fires immediately after `DOM` is parsed/ready but `window.onload` fires after all resources have been loaded, including all images, so `$(function () { // ... })` will fire once at first and then the `onload` event will fire again.

```
$(function () {
    console.log('reday event'); // this will fire at first
});

this.onload = function () {
    console.log('load event'); // this/second will fire after "ready" event
}
```

Also, remember, `window.onload` is equivalent of `jQuery`'s [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event, i.e. `$( window ).load(function() { // ... })`.

[Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bWr9V/2/), (both events fire one after another, `ready` then `onload`).

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to `window.onload = function () { };` Which will be triggered after all images have been loaded, etc.

`$(function () { });` or `$(document).ready(function () { });` is triggered after the DOM has been successfully created, and thus, when you can be certain you can select any/specific elements.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you would as they do basically the same thing, so there should be no issue.

Comment: `$(document).ready` doesn't wait for images, `window.onload` (or `$(window).load`) does.  I think.